# PHP Multidimensional Array Sorting with Data and Time

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am working with any multidimensional array Sorting when I need to sort the array with values and the values should be sorted according tot he date and time. How could I do that.

For Some situation I cant do that through Query I need to Sort through PHP Sort but the predefined function dosent help me.

My Array to be sorted:

```
Array
(
    [events] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 213532
                    [1] => 100% View  
                    [2] => 12/11/2014 09:00
                    [3] => 12/11/2014 11:00
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 213533
                    [1] => test 80  
                    [2] => 12/11/2014 06:00
                    [3] => 12/11/2014 08:00
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 213534
                    [1] => wf4  
                    [2] => 12/12/2014 00:00
                    [3] => 12/12/2014 23:59
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 213535
                    [1] => Standaard:  
                    [2] => 12/12/2014 10:00
                    [3] => 12/12/2014 12:00
                )
        )
)
```

Every Sub Array of [2] Value.

> ['events'][$i][2]

Should be sorted and rearranged. in the following way.

```
12/11/2014 06:00
12/11/2014 09:00
12/12/2014 00:00
12/12/2014 10:00
```

How can I do that any logical help will be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mario is right that usort is what you probably want.  You can also use strtotime to convert the string date to an integer, which is easy to compare.  I wrote up a working example here.  You'll see that I first print out the data (not sorted), then call usort with my custom sort function.  When I print out the array again, it's now in order by date.

```
function compare($a, $b) {
    $timeA = strtotime($a[2]);
    $timeB = strtotime($b[2]);
    if ($timeA < $timeB) {
        return -1;
    } 
    if ($timeA > $timeB) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

function printArrayContents($arr) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        echo $arr[$i][2] , "<BR>";
    }
}

$events = array(
    0 => array(
        0 => 213532,
        1 => '100% View',
        2 => '12/11/2014 09:00',
        3 => '12/11/2014 11:00'
    ),
    1 => array(
        0 => 213533,
        1 => 'test 80',
        2 => '12/11/2014 06:00',
        3 => '12/11/2014 08:00'
    ),
    2 => array(
        0 => 213534,
        1 => 'wf4',
        2 => '12/12/2014 00:00',
        3 => '12/12/2014 23:59'
    ),
    3 => array(
        0 => 213535,
        1 => 'Standaard:',
        2 => '12/12/2014 10:00',
        3 => '12/12/2014 12:00'
    )
);

echo "Unsorted:<BR>";
printArrayContents($events);

if (usort($events, "compare")) {
    echo "Sorted:<BR>";
    printArrayContents($events);
} else {
    echo "Sort failed.<BR>";
}
```

Output:

```
Unsorted:
12/11/2014 09:00
12/11/2014 06:00
12/12/2014 00:00
12/12/2014 10:00
Sorted:
12/11/2014 06:00
12/11/2014 09:00
12/12/2014 00:00
12/12/2014 10:00
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), which allows you to define your own callback/comparison function.

Essentially you'll want something like this:

```
function my_event_sorter($left, $right) {
    if ($left[2] == $right[2])
        return 0;
    return strtotime($left[2]) < strtotime($right[2]) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($events, 'my_event_sorter');
```

This comparison function will receive two parameters (the two elements to be compared) and it's supposed to return one of three integer values:

- `-1`: The left value is smaller than the right one (i.e. order is fine).
- `0`: Both values are identical (i.e. order is fine as well).
- `1`: The right value is smaller than the left one (i.e. order has to be swapped).

Answer (score 0):

if they are unique, you can use the datetime values as a key and then use ksort:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($events as $event){
    $newArray[$event[2]] = $event;
}
ksort($newArray);
```